# Can't connect to Google Cloud 2nd Gen from GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I backed up my Cloud SQL V1 DB to a bucket and restored to a new 2nd-gen instance. Connecting via the console works fine. I can select, look at procs etc. Connecting to it from my Java GAE app doesn't. The GAE app and the Cloud SQL DB are in the same project.

I get these values in the logs:

GAE log:

```
java.sql.SQLInvalidAuthorizationSpecException: Not authorized to access instance: xxxx
```

SQL log:

```
[Warning] User 'root'@'%' was assigned access 0x1fffffff but was allowed to have only 0x1fff7dff.
```

Any tips?

Comment: Please show what connection string you are using to connect to your instance.

Comment: Can you go to "IAM & Admin" section and check that you still have "App Engine default service account" there?

Comment: I do, and it's marked as an Editor. And under the App Engine Authorization of Cloud SQL, it says "Apps in this project: All authorized." and the app is in the same project as the Cloud SQL DB.

Comment: Anything else I might look out for, Vadim?

Comment: Hey, I just noticed that you are using jdbc:google:rdbms:// prefix where it should be jdbc:google:mysql://.

Comment: I think that's it! For some reason I've been using the old, deprecated prefix and you correctly pointed out the new one. Thank you. If you'd like, create an answer and I'll mark it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your JDBC URL uses the `jdbc:google:mysql://` prefix and not the old/deprecated `jdbc:google:rdbms://` prefix.

While `jdbc:google:rdbms://` continues to work for First Generation instances, it won't work when connecting to Second Generation instances. `jdbc:google:mysql://` will work for both.